# App is working in mobile and my own PC emulator but not in other PC

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have programmed an android app for my experiment. it is properly working in my mobile and also on emulator(tablet). but i have to perform that experiment in other computer which is fresh. i just downloaded same emulator (NOX) in 2nd computer and tried to run that app by copying apk to that emulator. App is not working on that computer. when i click it is just crashing. 
Could you please suggest me any solution.
i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace of the crash, and the relevant piece of code that the stacktrace refers to.

Comment: It is working properly on mobile and emulator on PC on which i have programmed but to run the same apk on other emulator or PC, do i have to install some special tools etc on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. i checked my logcat but its empty as the app is working well. but the PC on which i want to run that app does't have android studio. i just downloaded emulator for that and tried to run apk. but it is not working.

Comment: There might be several reasons which are causing this issue. So that is the best way to see error logs otherwise won't get across beyond of the guess. Even if you don't have Android Studio, Adb Logcat can be downloaded.

Comment: I think if there is a problem in coding then it should also not work  om mobile and 1st emulator. But it is working well. Sorry for asking again. i am not best with this as my department is different. i just made it for my experiment.